# Error sequelize: Invoice.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, sequelize

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación utilizando Sequelize con MySQL y estoy teniendo dificultades para establecer correctamente las relaciones entre mis modelos.

Estoy utilizando los siguientes códigos para definir mis modelos y sus relaciones:

user.model.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("./index");

const Product = require("./products.model");
const Invoice = require("./invoices.model");


const User = sequelize.define("User", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

User.hasMany(Product, { as: "products", foreignKey: "user_id" });
User.hasMany(Invoice, { as: "invoices", foreignKey: "buyer_id" });

module.exports = User;
```

products.model.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("./index");

const User = require("./user.model");
const Invoice = require("./invoices.model");

const Product = sequelize.define("Product", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  price: {
    type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.BLOB,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

Product.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
Product.hasMany(Invoice, { as: "invoices", foreignKey: "product_id" });

module.exports = Product;
```

invoice.model.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("./index");

const User = require("./user.model");
const Product = require("./products.model");

const Invoice = sequelize.define("Invoice", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
});

Invoice.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "buyer_id" });
Invoice.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: "product_id" });

module.exports = Invoice;
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo el siguiente error al intentar establecer una relación en mi modelo Invoice:

```
Error: Invoice.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

Alguien podría decirme si hay algún problema en mi código o si me estoy perdiendo de algo importante en la configuración de las relaciones?

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia sería muy apreciada. ¡Gracias!